# Define a typescript interface for an object that has dashes as the property name

Tags: typescript

I'd like to map

```json
{
  "controller-element": { }
}
```

into an `interface` but because `controller-element` has a `-` I can't simply do

```js
export interface IControllerResponse {
  controller-element: any;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just enclose the field name in quotes:

```
export interface IControllerResponse {
  "controller-element": any;
}


const response: IControllerResponse={
    "controller-element": 123
}
```

Comment: can you add a link to the spot in the documentation?

Comment: well, I couldn't find any explicit reference on that, but it seems natural to apply the same EcmaScript rules to TypeScript's such as types and interfaces.

Comment: didn't actually feel natural because it's using a string as a variable name. :D

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I say that you can compose an object by using a string as a field. That's just EcmaScript. By the way, TypeScript gives you interfaces and types, and offers the same syntax for the field definitions. As "natural", I meant the trasposition of the EcmaScript syntax to the TypeScript meta constructs.